# Does nginx supports ejb?

Tags: nginx, ejb

I have not manage to see whether or not nginx supports ejb.
I know that tomEE does.
But Meet nothing on the web for nginx

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

nginx is a web server and not an application server.

To use Jakarta Enterprise Beans (formerly: Enterprise Java Beans (EJB)), you need an application server like TomEE, Glassfish or any other implementation, which implements the related [specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/enterprise-beans/4.0/).